# IndexPath Swift TableView clicked column

Tags: swift, uitableview

With the following code I get the indexPath of the clicked button in the tableview:

```
@IBAction func btnClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let hitPoint = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: self.tableView)
    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: hitPoint){
        print(indexPath)
        print(indexPath.row)
    }
}
```

The first print is `[3, 0]` when I  clicked on the 3th row I get the  `0`, but I need the other value. The `3` in this case.

Comment: Better to Assign indexpath.row to Button.tag in cellForRowAtIndexPath then use tableView.indexPathForRow to get that cell the above method you mentioned is expensive to cpu.

Comment: It seems what you want is `indexPath.section`

Comment: Thanks @Sam_M!!!!

Comment: third row should print [2,0] not [3,0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

indexPath returns [section, row].

If you want to access section (the thing you referred to as column ) ,
use `indexPath.section`

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to handle button click in the cell and transfer the cell to your tableView controller via closure or your custom delegate method and then find out the indexPath of the cell.

UPD.

Just try to get `indexPath.section`

Comment: Why? It does return the correct values, except I wanna access the first item from the array returned, but got the second one.

Comment: @user1469734 because it the best practice :) maybe you should google some posts about iOS architecture (for example, clean arch.) to understand this.

Comment: How to do what you're saying?